# Feasible computer vision techniques for detecting and classifying animal faces

Tags: computer-vision

Detecting and classifying animal faces within an image is, it seems a challenging task. Animal faces vary wildly, and so I imagine that many pathways which are usually taken in human face detection are not feasible. So:

Given the large variation in animal faces, **are there any common approaches that could be used for their detection/localisation within an image and then classification?**

**EDIT:** More specifically, any *frontal* face shot of any animal. I've collected some photos that the technique/approach would need to classify:

[image: animal faces]

I can see that there are disadvantages in having such large variation in the data to be classified, but surely this is an advantage for some techniques?

Comment: To be honest, this sounds like it could be the subject of a series of PhD theses if it hasn't already been.

Comment: All animals, or particular groups? Do you want to detect the existence of a (semi-)frontal head (not necessarily a face), or identify a particular zebra? Should this work for fish, insects, snails and starfish as well? There are many types of animals (most are not mammals or even vertebrates).  
Please try to make our question more specific.

Comment: @AdiShavit I'm looking for a solution which has the potential to classify a frontal face photo of any species, insects and whales included. I'm not expecting to actually use it on every species, and would be pretty happy if for a start, it could classify the animals in the photos that I added to the question. Any ideas?

Comment: @Emmet Yeah, I know what you mean. There have been quite a few papers that I've found which concentrate on particular species, or track animals in videos and some slightly more general ones. I'm really just hoping to get a rudimentary proof of concept type thing going for general animal face classification in a still image.

Comment: In the early 90's, I saw a documentary where an AI running on a powerful “workstation” of the time grinds away for several minutes to decide whether an image was “pig” or “not pig”. Then a researcher picks up a toy from a table full of about 100 pig-like toys in all different shapes and sizes and shows it to a 3 year-old girl, asking “What's this?”. “It's a piggy”, she says, “they're all piggies”. She merely glanced at the table and knew they were all pigs. It's oddly humbling that even the most powerful supercomputer cannot compete with a small child when it comes to visual recognition tasks.

Comment: Well, to be fare a child has extra info about 3d of piggies tgat simplifies both segmentation and recognition. With mass use of Kinect we will get there without supercomputers.

Answer (score 0):

Note that predators  need binocular vision and thus their eyes are located in front (humans included). Prey have eyes on the sides for larger field of view and early detection of predators. I would concentrate on predators and try to find eyes for some reasonably homogeneous species. Handling a wide variety of animals from whales to insects sounds a bit over-optimistic.

Speaking of human face detection - it is not only face detection but also discarding non-faces about which in your case you did not say a word and may be not even gave a thought. Since you want to separate the face form background, You cannot concentrate on positive examples only unless they are very different from background which is not the case when animal are very heterogeneous. Thus segmentation of an animal face in general case would be a hard task.

Comment: Thanks for you thoughts, Vlad. Disregarding non-faces was addressed in the question: "are there any common approaches that could be used for their detection / **localisation** within an image and **then classification**?" I think you're right about concentrating on animals with binocular vision. Cheers

Comment: In your case detection and segmentation probably need to be done jointly

Comment: Ah, this sounds interesting - would you be able to expand on that a bit? I'm trying get an idea of a general approach that I could take

Comment: Since the task is quite difficult one may want to combine top down recognition with a bottom up segmentations as in http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~jshi/papers/obj_det_liming_accv07.pdf